# How to disable mat-icon-button hover background-color?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

Is it possible to disable the default state of hover on a `mat-icon-button`? I want to apply a custom hover effect on this button, but can't get rid of the default effect as it's still visibly there

```
<button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon>minimize</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Tried couple of methods by setting the `background-color` on transparent on hover state, adding the `!important` tag, but nothing seemed to work.

```
.mat-icon:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
```

```
.mat-mdc-icon-button:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override `mat-mdc-button-persistent-ripple::before` this.

```
.mat-mdc-icon-button:hover .mat-mdc-button-persistent-ripple::before {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/4splr1?file=src%2Fexample%2Fbutton-overview-example.css

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!
How did you figure this out? I struggled for more than 2 days trying to find anything on this subject,

Comment: i just looked inspect and used `:hover` all child elements :)